# How do you cycle through windows in Mathematica 7?

Tags: mathematica

How do you cycle through notebook windows in Mathematica 7?

Is there a shortcut?

The help system doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Mac you can use the system shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to cycle through the windows of an application, which works with Mathematica notebooks.

On Windows, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to cycle through open notebooks, but only in one direction.

See also the [list of keyboard shortcuts](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html).

Comment: Shift + Ctrl + F6 cycles in the other direction (Mathematica 9 under Windows 7)

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but ...

There exists two Front End commands : "CycleNotebooksBackward" and "CycleNotebooksForward", but AFAIK there is no shortcut assigned. Yoy may construct your own.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts/4209612#4209612) for more shortcuts.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

You may be also interested in [this Martin's answer](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/3nc8I6htwGU/SwRi07wc-84J) in the official newsgroup which explains how to bind <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> key for switching between opened notebooks:

> One only has to add the following
>   lines to the "KeyEventTranslations.tr"
>   file in order to have the Ctrl+Tab key
>   working in the front end of
>   Mathematica 8 as in Mathematica 4:
>
> Item[KeyEvent["Tab", Modifiers ->
>   {Control}],
>   FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["CycleNotebooksForward"]]]
>
> But this is really undocumented by
>   Wolfram Research, I wonder why ...